# Unable to resolve dependencies from test

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

I am new to scala. I am trying to create a scala project in IntellIj and adding a test class.
I am using the below 2 dependencies in sbt.

```
libraryDependencies += ("org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.8")
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
```

But I am unable to use the class FunSuite in the test class 'ProcessCSVTest.scala' for testing as it is giving a compilation error.

Although I can see the dependencies in the external library in my IntellIj

[image]

**Build.sbt file**

```
name := "CSVParser"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

libraryDependencies += ("org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.8")
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
```

The entire code can be found here - https://github.com/practice09/CSVParser

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see the import statement in the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is the test `ProcessCSVTest.scala` is under `main` sources which means ScalaTest needs to be on the main classpath, however in `build.sbt` ScalaTest dependency is scoped to the `Test` classpath

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
```

So if you remove `Test` scope like so

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8"
```

then ScalaTest will end up on the main classpath and we can add the following import

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
```

However my suggestion is to move the tests out of the main sources and put them under `src/test/scala/`, and then scope the dependency under `Test` like before

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
```

The following command builds an example with correct project structure expected by sbt

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
```

so try exploring how it is setup and fit your project to match.

Answer (score 0):

Because `FunSuite` is in a package, you need to add

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
```

If you put the cursor on it and [press `Alt+Enter`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-problems.html), you should get a suggestion to fix it.